How to read BIOS serial number?
In a PC running Windows, how could I read BIOS serial number and CPU serial number?
I use pascal, Delphi7.
The reason for this is that I want to identify a PC using something unique in order to protect my applications from unauthorized use.

Even if you could get the BIOS/CPU serial numbers (which, there is no Win32 API for that, you have to use assembly code to talk to the hardware directly), they can be easily faked by malicious users who are determined to circumvent your protections (via virtual machines, etc). You would only be able to deter casual users. Don't rely on hardware specs to uniquely identify PC users.

This answer explains how to uniquely identify a system. It can be circumvented by a malicious actor, but at least you didn't spend development resources on figuring out an elaborate scheme yourself.

latest delphi : https://blogs.embarcadero.com/easily-access-system-bios-information-from-windows-with-delphi/

@Franz You don't need latest Delphi in order to use the library that is being used in the linked article since the mentioned library supports legacy Delphi versions as low as Delphi 5
